How to have a character counter and limit a text field?
In my article content type, I have a "body" field, what I want is to limit the number of characters for this field.
For example, a user creates an article, a counter displays the number of characters and beyond 2 000 characters the user can no longer enter text.
This field uses CKeditor with Drupal 11

Like this? https://www.drupal.org/project/maxlength

@monalisa great thanks this module is great
